# Stuck at login after upgrading from 16.04 to 17.04/17.10

Tags: upgrade

I have a Dell Poweredge T20 that I installed a separate hard drive in dedicated to Ubuntu.

I followed [This guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-0417-04-to-ubuntu-17-10)

and after rebooting, I get to the login screen but mouse and keyboard are not functional. The system seems to be working, though, because I can see the sound icon go from "muted" to "not muted"

I've tried a different keyboard and mouse.

I installed Ubuntu for the purpose of getting to learn Linux better, but it's not off to a great start unfortunately...

Help? Thank you

Comment: It's hard to investigate or fix anything without a functional keyboard. It seems an upgrade wasn't a good idea in your case, in fact, it was unnecessary, as 16.04 also has the Linux kernel. I'd say, keep it simple, and stay with 16.04.

Comment: The keyboard works if I go to advanced options in grub -> network -> drop to root shell -> and type commands there. Is there a command I can try from there to reinstall input devices? It used to be xserver-xorg-input-all but looks like that no longer works

Comment: Try going in your bios and disabling "bios keyboard" or change something along the lines of "Let os detect keyboard" etc. There's other options that might affect this to that might be worded "pnp operating system" which should be enabled etc.